# Cannot open Boost library when building CMake project

Tags: c++, build, cmake

I want to build a CMake project using Visual Studio 2019 that requires Boost and multiple different libraries. When I'm building as static library there are no problems, but when I uncheck both BUILDSTATIC and LINKSTATIC I get:

```
fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'boost_thread-vc142-mt-x64-1_70.lib'
...
fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'boost_filesystem-vc142-mt-x64-1_70.lib'
```

despite that all the required variables seem to be set correctly:

```
Boost_DIR: D:/boost_1_70_0/boost
Boost_INCLUDE_DIR: D:/boost_1_70_0
Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_RELEASE: D:/boost_1_70_0/stage/lib
BOOST_LIBRARYDIR: D:/boost_1_70_0/stage/lib

Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE: D:/boost_1_70_0/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem-vc142-mt-x64-1_70.lib
Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE: D:/boost_1_70_0/stage/lib/libboost_system-vc142-mt-x64-1_70.lib
Boost_THREAD_LIBRARY_RELEASE: D:/boost_1_70_0/stage/lib/libboost_thread-vc142-mt-x64-1_70.lib
Boost_CHRONO_LIBRARY_RELEASE: D:/boost_1_70_0/stage/lib/libboost_chrono-vc142-mt-x64-1_70.lib
Boost_ATOMIC_LIBRARY_RELEASE: D:/boost_1_70_0/stage/lib/libboost_atomic-vc142-mt-x64-1_70.lib
Boost_DATE_TIME_LIBRARY_RELEASE: D:/boost_1_70_0/stage/lib/libboost_date_time-vc142-mt-x64-1_70.lib
```

What the problem may be?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to build dynamic Boost libraries and then link against them instead of linking to static libs.